# How to prevent an Object being cast to a String automatically

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-conversion, java-6

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
public class FileEntry {
    private String name;
    public FileEntry (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

void foo(String arg){};
foo("string" + new FileEntry("")); // How to get a compile error here
```

How can I make java give me a compile error instead of automatically converting the Object to a String?

Comment: "I use this class on a method with a String argument" - wait, wat? So mean, when you pass the result of a method call? What's that method's return type?

Comment: Show us example code in which you are using it which throws the exception.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink your design a bit. Under what circumstances would you need this?

Comment: I don't believe what I think I understand. Can you show the actual code where a 'conversion to string' happens?

Comment: @delnan - yeah I don't understand this. Surely passing FileEntry to a method that takes a String will result in a compile error?

Comment: Um, don't pass it to a method that takes a `String` as an argument? Some times you actually have to think about what you're doing rather than relying on something to tell you.

Comment: Edited my question above. I used to pass this around as a string and now I have switched to a class instead. Hence the compiler did not fetch all the places I needed to actually change the code and there was a silent error instead.

Comment: The object isn't 'automatically converted to a String'. It already is a String. That's what the '+' operator is defined to yield when the first argument is a String. There's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have

```
void foo(String bar)
{

}
```

and you call

```
foo(new FileEntry());
```

there will be a compiler error. See [here](http://ideone.com/BhFTF)

The the toString() will be called only if you do something like

```
foo("this is foo" + new FileEntry());
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. You are right. The problem arouse in a string conversion. However it would be nice if there was a way to detect this compile time. Will edit my question

Answer (score 6):

it is impossible to do it in the compile time. in the runtime you can throw an exception from the overridden toString method

Answer (score 4):

Calling `toString()` is *not* the same as casting - you need to be aware of the difference.

You could override `toString()` to not only throw an exception, but be deprecated:

```
@Deprecated @Override
public String toString() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("toString mustn't be called on this class");
}
```

That will *only* help at compile-time if the compile-time type of the expression is `FileEntry`. It will also just be a warning under most configurations.

This will also potentially confuse debuggers which try to call `toString()` automatically, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any other way than to override `toString()` and throw an Exception inside.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use this class on a method with a
>   String argument the java compiler will
>   automatically convert this to a String
>   object using toString()

No, it won't. What it will do is call an overloaded method that takes an `Object` parameter, if such a method exists - and such methods often call `toString()` on the parameter.

There's nothing you can do to prevent overloaded methods from being used - they were put there on purpose, after all.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `"str" + obj` does not involve a type cast.

It does not involve overloading either, or a call to `String.concat(String)`.  (Indeed, `str1.concat(str2)` gives a different result to `str1 + str2` when `str2` is `null`!)

Technically speaking, this is called a "string conversion"; see [JLS 5.1.11](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.11).  The conversion is *equivalent to* a call to `String.valueOf(Object)` or a call to the static `toString(primitive)` method of the relevant primitive wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't understand what exactly is going on. But FileEntry@6e470ce1 is probably the result of the toString method of FileEntry. You can overwrite that to return whatever you want, as long as it is a String.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you wouldn't just implement the `toString()` method in `FileEntry`. If you really want a compile error, you can make a base abstract class like:

```
public abstract class ForceImplementToString {
  @Override
  public abstract String toString();
}
```

Then create your class like this, it will create a compile error that you have to implement the `toString()` method:

```
public class FileEntry extends ForceImplementToString {
    private String name;
    public FileEntry (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class has a `toString()` that is inherited by every Class in Java (since very class derives from `Object`). This `toString()` will be called (unless it is overridden, in which case that particular object's overridden `toString()` will be called).

There is nothing you can do to prevent this from happening.

On another note, what does your method look like? If you have `public myMethod(String arg)` and you call `myMethod(new FileEntry())`, I'm pretty sure that results in a compile-time error.

Of course, if you have an overloaded method that has `Object arg` as a parameter, then that's the method that will be called. Internally, this method is probably calling `toString()` on `arg`. Also, using an object that is not a string in a string context (for example, if you concatenate it to a string), results in an implicit call to that object's `toString()` (which can be the overridden one, or the default from from `Object`).

To get a prettier result from `toString()`, you should override `toString()` in the `FileEntry` class so that it prints something that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your premise is correct. Java does not automatically convert objects to strings. This code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        String got = "Concatenated: ".concat(foo);
        System.out.println(got);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo object";
    }
}
```

produces this output from my Java 1.6.0_23 compiler:

```
Foo.java:4: concat(java.lang.String) in java.lang.String cannot be applied to (Foo)  
            String got = "Concatenated: ".concat(foo);
                                         ^
1 error
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always download the source for java, and remove toString() from Object.

Comment: Then it would not be java any more